# Javascript string in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, string

I'm new to PHP and I don't understand why this piece of code doesn't work. Can somebody please help me?

```
    $alertver = '<div class="col s12 '. $_POST["alert"] .'"><span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>'. $textstrong . $_POST["alerttext"] ."</div>";
```

When I try to select this from my mysql database the 'none' part of this code doesn't work.

When I try to use this code: `$alertver = '<div class="col s12 '. $_POST["alert"] .'">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\';">&times;</span>'. $textstrong . $_POST["alerttext"] ."</div>";`

It gives me this MySQL error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'none';">&times;</span><strong>1233</strong> 56</div>'`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Mixing *three different languages* on *one line of code* is just begging for string quoting problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onclick you have single quote you should escape  with proper escape char \

```
$alertver = '<div class="col s12 ' . $_POST["alert"] .'">
                <span class="closebtn" 
                onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\'; ">&times;</span>'
                . $textstrong . $_POST["alerttext"] ."</div>";
```

If you store the data in bb you can try

```
$alertver = '<div class="col s12 ' . $_POST["alert"] .'">
                <span class="closebtn" 
                onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=  '  .
                          'none'  .  '; ">&times;</span>'
                . $textstrong . $_POST["alerttext"] ."</div>";
```

Comment: When I select this code from my database I get this MySQL error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'none';">&times;</span><strong>1233</strong> 56</div>'"

Comment: Yes I use it with this MySQL code: `$sql = "UPDATE Alerts SET Alert='{$alertver}' WHERE id=3"; `

Comment: seems dangeroues to me .. an unexpeted sequence of char could break you code ... .. for me should be better  save the related param and build the code dinamically with php  .. anyway ..everyone code like prefer ..

Answer (score 1):

You have not escaped the single quotes around none. Try this.

```
$alertver = '<div class="col s12 '. $_POST['alert'] .'"><span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\';">&times;</span>'. $textstrong . $_POST['alerttext'] .'</div>';
```